# Load document in detail view

Tags: ipad

I am trying to load an document (word/excel/pdf etc) through the "Open In" functionality into my split view. My detail view consists of an web view which will display these files. I'm able to get the URL in the app delegate using the following code

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
    {
        //Loading webpage in webview by passing url
        NSURL *urlToPass = url;
        [objWeb passWebURL:urlToPass];
        return YES;
    }
```

But the file is not been loaded in the detail view. I have created a function to accept this URL in the detail view.

```
-(void)passWebURL:(NSURL *)strURL
{
    NSLog(@"URL PASSED IS:: %@", strURL);
    passedURL = strURL;
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:passedURL];
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:requestURL delegate:self];
    [urlConnection start];
    [viewToDisplay loadRequest:requestURL];
}
```

But I'm not sure as to where to call his method as the file is not getting displayed.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Do you see your NSLog line getting executed?

Comment: Yes the NSLog gets executed. But there are some issues. The split view controller gets exexuted and the NSLog in splitView is null. When I put the app in background and open any document in the browser and using "OpenIn" I open it in my app, then the NSLog in AppDelegate shows me the URL, but the Detail View NSLog is still null. The document does not get loaded in the detail view. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: well, i was able to get the issue solved. The main problem was that the detail view being set as delegate of splitview was called first. as a result of which the NSLog always showed null. I just moved it to appdelegate and called the function over there. Now the web view in detail view gets loaded whenever a file is opened through web browser using "Open In"